# Firmware image file to flash memory

Tags: linux, firmware

I have a device firmware image.
Now, I want mount this image file to flash memory.

in install file of this image file is like this code:

```
if [ -e BOOT.bin ]; then
    flash_erase /dev/mtd0 0x0 0x80 >/dev/null 2>&1
    nandwrite -p -s 0x0 /dev/mtd0 ./BOOT.bin >/dev/null 2>&1
    rm -rf BOOT.bin
fi

if [ -e devicetree.dtb ]; then
    flash_erase /dev/mtd0 0x1020000 0x1 >/dev/null 2>&1
    nandwrite -p -s 0x1020000 /dev/mtd0 ./devicetree.dtb >/dev/null 2>&1
    rm devicetree.dtb
fi

if [ -e uImage ]; then 
  flash_erase /dev/mtd0 0x1100000 0x40 >/dev/null 2>&1
  nandwrite -p -s 0x1100000 /dev/mtd0 ./uImage >/dev/null 2>&1
  rm uImage
fi

if [ -e rootfs.jffs2 ]; then
  if [ -f /dev/mtd3 ];then
      flash_erase /dev/mtd2 0x0 0x1E0 >/dev/null 2>&1
  else
      flash_erase /dev/mtd2 0x0 0x280 >/dev/null 2>&1
  fi
  nandwrite -p -s 0x0 /dev/mtd2 ./rootfs.jffs2 >/dev/null 2>&1
  rm rootfs.jffs2
fi
```

How can I do it?